# NullReferenceException was unhandled in datarow array C#

Tags: c#

I get the NullReferenceException while i execute the below piece of code.

```
private void Move(bool isRight)
{
     SaveSelected();

     // Move the selected items over
     for (int index = 0; index < this.DataSource.Rows.Count; index++)
     {
           DataRow row = this.DataSource.Rows[index];

          if (isRight && (bool)row["IsSelected"] == true &&
             (bool)row["HasResult"] == false ||
             !isRight && (bool)row["IsSelected"] == false)
          {
               // move it by setting a flag which is used by the view
                   row["LeftSide"] = !isRight;
          }
      }
      this.BindData(EventArgs.Empty);       
}
```

please provide me with a solution.

Thanks,
Niranjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points where the exception can be happening.

I suggest that you check if the columns `IsSelected`, `HasResult` and `LeftSide` exist AND their values are boolean values; if they are not, the `(bool)` typecasts you're doing will trigger this kind of exception. Null values will cause this problem too.

If the columns have the expected values, check if the method `SaveSelected` is not throwing the exception.

It'll be move valuable if you provide us the exact line which trigger the exception.

Comment: The Exception is thrown in this below line.    row["LeftSide"] = !isRight;

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your debugger will provide you where it went wrong. It is probably that either column name IsSelected, HasResult, LeftSide does not exists.